# Updating widgets from a slot after its connected by a signal from another class

Tags: qt, python-3.5, pyqt5

I am using two windows, schedule and clock. clock window is opened by a button in schedule window and after that, time is set in the clock function.

```
def Add_new_schedule(self):#slot for adding new schedule using clock
    if(self.TABLE_LENGTH == 5):

        self.TOAST_WARNING.setText("LIMIT REACHED!")
    else:
        from Clock import Ui_Clock

        self.CLOCK_UI = Ui_Clock()
        self.CLOCK_UI.showFullScreen()
```

And then after setting the time details, a signal in clock passes the values of time into a slot in the schedule window. and after some adjustments, its passed to set a table with the data.

```
def Get_clock_values(self, TIME_DETAILS):

    self.close()

    self.SCHEDULE.setText("")

    CURRENT_DATA = {}

    CURRENT_DATA['start_time'] = TIME_DETAILS['START_HOUR']+":"+TIME_DETAILS['START_MINUTE']
    CURRENT_DATA['end_time'] = TIME_DETAILS['END_HOUR']+":"+TIME_DETAILS['END_MINUTE']
    CURRENT_DATA['duration_time'] = TIME_DETAILS['DURATION_HOUR']+":"+TIME_DETAILS['DURATION_MINUTE']
    CURRENT_DATA['node_1'] = True
    CURRENT_DATA['node_2'] = True
    CURRENT_DATA['node_3'] = True
    CURRENT_DATA['node_4'] = True

    self.DATA_FROM_DB.append(CURRENT_DATA)
    self.TABLE_LENGTH = len(self.DATA_FROM_DB)
    self.Set_table()
```

The Set_table() is supposed to update some widgets already defined when schedule is invoked. However this is not working, the widgets are not null,
and this function works when dummy values are set in DATA_FROM_DB, and Set_table() is called without involving another window. There is no issue with the data that is passed.

Or if there are better ways to do this, that is also welcome.

Comment: You could share the entire project so you can test it

Comment: Its company's IP, so I can't do that.

Comment: Or some similar example where the same error is reproduced